# Convert LineString to MultiLineString in Qgis Spatialite

Tags: qgis, spatialite, linestring

How to convert LineString to MultiineString layer in sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS you can use the vector tool:
**Vector->Geometry Tools->Single parts to Multipart**

Singles parts must have a same attribute to became a multipart.
and finally you can load it in spatialite.

Comment: Small addendum, these days the tool is called "Collect geometries" :)